# Tomcat start from Eclipse and startup.sh

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, ubuntu

Strange things happen. I can start Tomcat from both Eclipse and startup.sh. Runnig from Eclipse I can access localhost:8080 while running from startup.sh I cant. What could be the problem? Ubuntu 11.10. From Eclipse netstat displays 127.0.0.1:8080 as ESTABLISHED and from startup.sh as CLOSE_WAIT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was caused by incorrect installation. Everything is solved. Close.

Comment: Could you document _what_ was incorrect about your installation and what the symptoms of the problem were?