# Tomcat 404 error trying to access webapp

Tags: web-services, tomcat, maven

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Tomcat start from Eclipse and startup.sh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11172665/tomcat-start-from-eclipse-and-startup-sh)

I've manually installed tomcat 7 on Ubuntu 11.10. Learning jax-ws with eclipse\maven I try to manually figure out all the steps. I've done all the steps required, coding, wsgen, sun-jaxws.xml, web.xml. I can successfully deploy my web service to tomcat, however I can't access it getting 404 error. At the same time my app is displayed as running in tomcat manager. What could be the problem?

Comment: What is the name of your `.war`/application and which URL are you accessing? Which HTTP method are you using?

Comment: The name is JAXWS.war and I access localhost:8080/JAXWS/service, the service url-pattern is from the web.xml and sun-jaxws.xml.

Comment: Oh... and now I've got the UnsupportedClassVersionError exception starting the service...

Comment: You probably compiled your source code with a JVM newer than the JVM which runs Tomcat.

Comment: Thanks. That was exactly the cause :)
Closed.